# Replace regex pattern string with empty Scala

Tags: scala

```
   val test = "63760980|0|0.0|0;|0"

the output that I am looking for 63760980||||
```

I have tried the below way but it removes the characters from diff word/letters

```
test.replaceAll("0(\\.0|;|)", "").replaceAll("\\|0\\|","\\|\\|")
scala> test.replaceAll("0(\\.0|;|)", "")
res25: String = 637698||||
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are rather ill-defined.

The simple solution is just to remove everything after a bar `|` character.

```
"63760980|0|0.0|0;|0".replaceAll("\\|[^|]+", "|")
//res0: String = 63760980||||
```

But that might be *too* simple for your actual needs.

More examples, positive and negative, would be useful.

---

At some point regex might not be the best tool for the job.

```
"63760980|0|0.0|0;|0|hello|test|768|0.9"
  .split("\\|").map {
    case "0"|"0.0"|"0;" => ""
    case s => s
  }.mkString("|")
//res2: String = 63760980|||||hello|test|768|0.9
```

---

But if you have your heart set on a regex solution...

```
"0;|63760980|0|0.0|0;|0|hello|test|768|0.9|0.0"
  .replaceAll("(?<=(^|\\|))(0|0\\.0|0;)(?=(\\||$))", "")
//res3: String = |63760980|||||hello|test|768|0.9|
```

...things just get a little more complicated.

Comment: No, that's not what I was looking for , the line contains around 10k columns which has actual data, I only want to replace the 0 , 0; , 0.0 characters from the pipe delimiter

Comment: example: "63760980|0|0.0|0;|0|hello|test|768|0.9" => result should be
"63760980|||||hello|test|768|0.9"

Comment: Thanks, it might be expensive but I think is the only way now.